# Fullscreen Video on a dual monitor setup

Tags: flash, youtube, multiple-monitors, silverlight

I like to watch youTube videos and Netflix videos while working/playing/surfing. Youtube is Flash and Netlix is silverlight. I have two Monitors on my Windows 7 box, how can I do full screen YouTube or Netflix while working on the other monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the Silverlight window to your second monitor & hit full screen, it will go on fullscreen for that monitor.

As for Flash, it doesn't support full screen in one monitor only, [atleast not officially.](http://lifehacker.com/5560912/keep-flash-101-in-full-screen-on-a-second-monitor)

Answer (score 3):

I have not tried this but maybe you could:

1. Set up a virtual machine on your computer like [Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org/)
2. Set your the virtual machine to full screen
3. Run your YouTube or netflix videos in the virtual machine
4. Work on your other computer.